# Website interactive script to validate specific state after series of interactions

Tags: browser, ui-automation, browser-automation, user-interaction

My main goal is to be able to see if the state on the website has changed. In order to see the desired state I need to do few clicks. Information that I am looking for is not present on the website when it is finished loading.

With which tool I can automate this route – load website, click through a few steps of the form, validate, if desired state is present, if not, try in 10 minutes?

Comment: You can use Selenium (https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to do this I think.

Comment: This is "Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources" which is a reason for closing. Please don't use bounties to ask off-topic questions.

Comment: While there are tools available, vanilla JS should also be able to handle this. Could trigger on page load if it's your own website, or with a bookmarklet if it's not. As Gert and Mofi say though, this is an off-topic question as it stands currently.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Puppeteer, Playwright, Selenium or Cypress.

Comment: An off-topic question seeking just for software tools should not be answered with an answer just offering a such tools even on question draws more attention with a bounty. The answer should at least demonstrate how the tool(s) can be used to achieve the goal. That is nearly impossible for this question as there is nothing written in the question which could be used for writing code using one of the suggested tools. @Haneen You should delete your answer on the off-topic question which brings you back two reputation points caused by my down vote which costs me one reputation point.